# Jmeter(Testing tool) with worklight

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to use jmeter with worklight. I followed the IBM knowledge center and could extract the wl instance from init.But when try to use the login function , it is showing unauthorized 401 and the response is not the authstatus required ,instead it is displaying another instance id. Give me suggestion and document for solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your test script, it is difficult to answer this question.

However, something to look at is:

1. Is the instance ID the same one in all trials or not?

   If it is the same instance ID then you are likely not properly extracting the instance ID.
   If is is not the same instance ID, you might have a configuration problem in the HTTP cookie manager in jMeter. It would be better to see the script.
2. What exactly did follow from the IBM Knowledge Center? Please provide the link.